# As someone starting out in RL, could you help me understand the differences between actor-only, critic-only, and actor-critic methods?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, actor-critic-methods, value-based-methods, policy-based-methods

I have been reading some medium articles and these three methods pop up a lot. I am wondering what the differences between these are, what are the advantages of one over the other, etc. Also from my understanding, actor-only method is synonymous to policy gradient methods, critic-only method is synonymous to value-based methods, and actor-critic methods use policy gradient methods for the actor part and value-based methods for the critic part. Am I correct? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Finally, what should one keep in mind when considering one or the other for their projects?

Comment: You're asking many questions here. I think they can barely be in the same post, provided that you edit your post to emphasize what your main question is and the other questions are just sub-questions that would also help to answer the main one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. My main question would be what the difference is between these three: actor-only, critic-only, and actor-critic methods.